# How to enable Application to react to KeyInput Events without beeing on Focus? c#

Tags: c#, input, background

I´m working on an Application, build with c#, which can be controlled by a 3D Mouse a an Input Device (I only use the 3D Mouse for this purpose). 
I´m having the problem, that this is only working, if the Window Form from the Application is on Focus, but I need the communication to be working, without having the Window on focus (I will remove the Window at all, once everything is working).
does anybody know how to do that? Having the 3D Mouse communicate to the Application, no matter what Appliction is on Focus?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using mouse and keyboard hooks:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/netwin32hooks.aspx

Comment: I thought about hooks too, I´m just not sure how to use them with a "second" Mouse, which is not supposed to have any mouse functionality. I thought about Raw Input, too. What do you think works better or easier?

Comment: I never used Raw input but as I can see it should do the trick... Just found: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/raw_keylogger.aspx Probably will use it for a project of mine. Thanks for the suggestion